# Annoying 1 px line at bottom of screen in fullscreen mode IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I have a problem that is only apparent in Internet Explorer (of course) but I am required to create the web page for IE 11. When using the following in my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url("bground.jpg");      
    background-size:cover;
    overflow: hidden;   
}
```

I always get a 1 px white line at the bottom of the screen where it cuts off the overflow (this is in full screen mode by the way). Everywhere I look says to use overflow: hidden or manually set the px dimensions or adjust width, height, margins, padding, etc. which doesn't seem to work. When trying to get rid of the overflow to ditch the scrollbars it seems that no matter what I do, the white line remains. I have also tried

```
-ms-overflow-style: none;
```

with the same result.

Is there potentially a way to accomplish this through jquery or javascript?

Comment: Could you show us more of your code or do a https://jsfiddle.net/ ?

Comment: Unfortunately, jsfiddle doesn't seem to do the trick as, to reproduce the issue, it requires the browser to display in full screen mode. However, it seems that I may have overcomplicated the question. After some further testing, just by simply doing: `<body bgcolor="#0000FF"> ` and hitting F11 in Internet Explorer, I am able to reproduce the issue. It doesn't matter whether or not it's formatted in the HTML or the CSS. I am now wondering if it is simply a graphical error for Internet Explorer in full screen mode in general... Any thoughts?